# Equivalent of UISegmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex in UISwtich- Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I'm trying to convert a UISegmentedControl to a UISwitch. I was successful on checking the state of the switch.

And then I saw this line of code:

```
self.mobile3GSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = [mConfigurationService getBoolWithKey:NETWORK_USE_3G];
```

I tried to guess on how UISwitch do it. So...

```
self.mobile3GSwitch.state = [mConfigurationService getBoolWithKey:NETWORK_USE_3G];
```

and then I get this error:

> Property 'selectedSegmentIndex' not found on object of type UISwitch

I know that UISwitch is not a segment and returns YES or NO. The error  is not the focus here. What I'm trying to understand is how can I convert the segment line of code to make it work for UISwitch.

I'm pretty much lost right now. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Yes I know that. My question different from your answer.

Comment: Share implementation of the method `getBoolWithKey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a simple function [`setOn`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISwitch/setOn:animated:) (Assuming your method for returning bool is correct).

```
[_mobile3GSwitch setOn:[mConfigurationService getBoolWithKey:NETWORK_USE_3G] animated:NO];
```

Comment: I'm using a really old library. This is getBoolWithKey -(BOOL)getBoolWithKey: (NSString*)key{
 return [defaults boolForKey:key];
}

Thanks for the answer. This is my first time dealing with switches so I just need to ask for help since I don't have much time with this project.

Comment: Ah well then your method is safe. Nothing wrong with it. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

`UISwitch` is binary: on or off. It has as a property `on`, not a selected segment index, as there are no segments.
When you get stuck, it is always a good idea to checkout the documentation from Apple: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/).